# nginx error while trying to serve django page

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm new at server setup. I'm trying to set up an EC2 instance to serve a Django app through nginx. I'm able to run and connect to the Django app using

```
python managy.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

However, while trying to setup the nginx to serve Django, I get the following error:

> 2013/05/22 06:19:25 [crit] 10035#0: *8 connect() to
>   unix:///home/ubuntu/web/something.com/something_uwsgi.sock failed (2:
>   No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   50.156.16.40, server: jamsnap.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///home/ubuntu/web/something.com/something_uwsgi.sock:",
>   host: "ec2.something.com"

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: i followed the guide here - http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/setting-aws-ec2-instance-nginx-django-uwsgi-and-mysql/#sthash.oiXyFlgK.D9bmiyIw.dpbs Everything else seems to work fine but I get stuck at this error. Could you help?

Comment: Something is wrong with that init script. You have to debug it. That socket files is not being created. Maybe uwsgi is not running. Try digging into it and post more details.

Comment: thanks for the direction - will try learning more about that and post results!